# Como verificar se um ionicModal está aberto?

Tags: ionic

Olá,
Como saber se um ionicModal está aberto? Preciso verificar se um ionicModal está aberto, caso esteja preciso fecha-lo para que não abra dois ionicModal ao mesmo tempo

Comment: ionic 1, 2 ou 3 ?

Comment: Ionic framework  1

Answer (score 1):

[Conforme a documentação](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/$ionicModal/), toda vez que você faz uma chamada

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplate(...)
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(...)
```

receberá uma **nova** promise de [ionicModal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/controller/ionicModal/). O método que você está procurando é o [isShown](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/controller/ionicModal/).

```
if (ionicModal.isShown()) { // se a janela está visível ...
    ionicModal.hide(); // fecha ...
}
```

O que pode ocorrer, é que mais de um lugar possa querer criar esses modais e você não vai ter acesso a essas referências, neste caso, você precisa implementar um mecanismo própio para controlar quantos modais estão abertos (fazer um factory que instancia esses modais e guarda as referências, ou, usar os [eventos que o $ionicModal emite](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/$ionicModal/)) e/ou se quer sobrescrever um modal.